# Prokhorov theorem in locally compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: probability, general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

[Prokhorov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem) gives a compactness condition in the space of probability measures on a Polish space. I am wondering whether we have similar conditions for probability measures on more general spaces, say, locally compact Hausdorff spaces, which seems to me to be a more natural setting of measure theory.

However, since the proofs that I have seen for Prokhorov theorem depend heavily on the completeness and separability of the underlying space, they do not help much when one tries to extend the result to more general spaces. And to my best guess such an extension would rely on techniques from functional analysis.

So, do we actually have such a condition for more general spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: I should pose this as a question. My impression is that Prokhorov's is a statement about sequential compactness. The set of probability measures, as the dual of $C_0(X)$, is compact in the weak-$^*$ topology for any LCH $X$ by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem. To make the weak-$^*$ topology metrizable, one needs separability conditions on $X$ or imposes restrictions on the measures considered (like uniform tightness).

Comment: Regarding LCH spaces being more natural: one of the major realms of application for measure theory is probability.  In probability, Polish spaces are very useful.  A simple way to think of this is as soon as you are interested in stochastic processes (basically an old-fashioned term for "random functions"), you're doing measure theory in a function space --- which is typically not locally compact.  Many constructions of Brownian motion, for example, avail themselves of Prokhorov's Theorem.  Same for point processes (which can be analyzed as random measures).  See Billingsley's book for more.

Answer (score 5):

There *is* a version of Prokhorov's theorem on locally compact Hausdorff spaces, but it seems surprisingly difficult to locate it in the literature.

One reference (that simultaneously gives both the LCH and Polish space versions) is [Bourbaki's Intégration. Chapitre IX](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0276436), Section 5.5, Théorème 1 + Théorème 2 (each theorem gives one implication). I'll summarize.

**Definition (Prokhorov condition)** Let $H$ be a collection of complex measures on a topological space $X$. $H$ is Prokhorov if

1. the total variations $|\mu|(X)$ of $\mu\in H$ are uniformly bounded, and
2. for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is a compact $K=K_{\varepsilon}\subseteq X$ such that $|\mu|(X-K)<\varepsilon$ for all $\mu\in H$.

Then:

**Theorem 1 (Prokhorov $\Rightarrow$ compact)** A Prokhorov set of complex measures on a [completely regular](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space) space $X$ (in particular an LCH space or a metric space) is relatively compact in the weak$^*$ topology on complex measures relative to the bounded continuous functions on $X$.

**Theorem 2 (compact $\Rightarrow$ Prokhorov)** If $X$ is LCH or complete metric separable then a weak$^*$-compact set of *positive* finite measures on $X$ is Prokhorov.

Comment: This version can also be found as Theorem 8.6.7. in Bogachev's Measure Theory Volume 2.